# custom Jquery plugin bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, notifications, tooltip

I've created a simple plugin following tuts+ and modified it to do what I want.
It basically creates a "tooltip" that I am trying to leave visible for a certain amount of time but also allow the user to click on the block so more of a notification than a tool tip. What I have so far is below, but when it doesn't auto hide...on click to close work however. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong/improvements?

```
$.fn.betterTooltip = function(options){

    /* Setup the options for the tooltip that can be 
       accessed from outside the plugin              */
    var defaults = {
        speed: 200,
        delay: 300,
        hideAfter:5000
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    /* Create a function that builds the tooltip 
       markup. Then, prepend the tooltip to the body */
    getTip = function() {
        var tTip = 
        "<div class='tip'>" +
        "<div class='tipMid'>"  +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='tipBtm'></div>" +
        "</div>";
        return tTip;
    }
    $("body").prepend(getTip());

    /* Give each item with the class associated with 
       the plugin the ability to call the tooltip    */
    $(this).each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var tip = $('.tip');
        var tipInner = $('.tip .tipMid');

        var tTitle = (this.title);
        this.title = "";

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var tLeft = offset.left;
        var tTop = offset.top;
        var tWidth = $this.width();
        var tHeight = $this.height();

        /* Delay the fade-in animation of the tooltip */
        setTimer = function() {
            $this.showTipTimer = setInterval("showTip()", defaults.delay);
        }
        hideTip=function(){
            stopTimer();
            tip.hide();
        }
        stopTimer = function() {
            clearInterval($this.showTipTimer);
            clearInterval( $this.hideTimer);
        }

        /* Position the tooltip relative to the class 
           associated with the tooltip                */
        setTip = function(top, left){
            var topOffset = tip.height()-30;
            var xTip = (left+60)+"px";
            var yTip = (top-topOffset)+"px";
            tip.css({
                'top' : yTip, 
                'left' : xTip
            });
        }

        /* This function stops the timer and creates the
           fade-in animation                          */
        showTip = function(){
            stopTimer();
            tip.animate({
                "top": "+=20px", 
                "opacity": "toggle"
            }, defaults.speed);
        }
        $(this).ready(function() {
            tipInner.html(tTitle+'<br />(Click to dismiss)');
            setTip(tTop, tLeft);
            setTimer();
            hideTimer=function(){
                $this.hideTimer=setInterval("hideTip()",defaults.hideAfter);
            }
            hideTimer();
        });
        $(tip).click(function() {
                hideTip();
        }); 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` instead of the `...Interval` versions you have. The former fire their callbacks once, whereas the latter do it repeatedly.

Some tips:

1. Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for the code to run - use a function pointer. I find it's much less error prone and scoping is never an issue.
2. Hide the tip on a `mouseleave` event (either from the item that the tip is for or the tip itself), and show it on `mouseover` or `mouseenter`. This is more efficient than having javascript running all the time.

Comment: Thank you i've made the changes, :-)